# Angular 2 - Template?

Tags: javascript, laravel, typescript, angular

Em uma estrutura como esta:

```
<header></header>
<main> 
   div1: <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   div2: <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   div3: <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Eu tenho essa estrutura no meu `app.componente.html`. Ocorre que as minhas rotas (paginas), terão elementos (outras `divs`, `inputs`, `table`, etc) que irão compor partes diferentes do templates (`div1`, `div2`, `div3`,`div4`, etc..) Consegui ser claro?

Como monto essa estrutura no angular? Consigo montar esta estrutura no `Laravel` utilizando as `Session`.

Comment: Não deu pra entender sua dúvida. Tente sempre por trechos de código na pergunta para que possamos entender melhor.

Comment: To vendo algo do tipo: Pass data from parent to child with input binding